# TypeScript: How to show all type members instead of higher order types

Tags: typescript

I'm making some mapped types in my project and I'm *pretty* sure they're working correctly, but something that would make it much easier would be seeing what the types explicitly map to.

```js
type OptionalKeys<T> = Exclude<
  {
    [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K;
  }[keyof T],
  undefined
>;

type RequiredKeys<T> =  Exclude<keyof T, OptionalKeys<T>>;

interface Foo {
  a: Date;
  b?: Date;
}

type StringFoo = (
  Partial<Record<OptionalKeys<Foo>, string> &
  Record<RequiredKeys<Foo, string>>
);
```

This works great, except when I mouse over the type to inspect it, this is what I see

```js
type StringFoo = Partial<Record<"b", string>> & Record<"a", string>
```

That's kind of opaque. Is there a way to make it show up as this instead?

```js
type StringFoo = {
  b?: string;
} & {
  a: string;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use braces with an index signature rather than the `Record` type:

```
type StringFoo = (
  {[key in OptionalKeys<Foo>]?: string} & 
  {[key in RequiredKeys<Foo>]: string}
);

// {
//     b?: string | undefined;
// } & {
//     a: string;
// }
```

Comment: This works for the contrived example I created for the question, but I have more complicated types in my project that compose several mapped types. It's not always possible to restructure things this way.